# How best to deal with this crumbling interior brickwork?

Tags: brick, masonry, mortar

While I was repainting the interior, some plaster started coming off the old  brickwork in my new house. I now have a 50cm by 50cm hole. Underneath, the mortar is crumbling and some bricks are cracked. I'd like to plaster over this hole, but first I need to patch up the mortar. Two questions:

- Is this easy to do myself? I'm a DIY beginner. If so, is there an easier way than mixing a load of lime mortar, for this small job?
- Should I be worried that there are underlying problems with the brickwork? The survey said the house was structurally sound. I'm not sure whether this level of damage is normal for a house this old (c. 1800) or if it might reveal other issues.

[image: brickwork]
[image: brickwork 2]

Comment: It was likely caused by moisture from behind, the million dollar question is whether THAT problem has already been dealt with....

Comment: Hmm... yup, that figures. There is damp coming in from the outside. I am going to fix that, but should I wait before trying to fix this? Or should I go ahead and fix this side of things?

Comment: If you still have a moisture problem that must be fixed first. If there is still moisture from behind and you fix this surface damage first, it will just come back in short time.